# Как добавить исключение в random.choice()

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
persons = ["Koga", "Lian", "Rex", "Androxus", "Shaurma"]
choosett = random.choice(persons)
```

Как добавить исключение для рандома из выбора в списке, например чтобы он не выбрал вторую ячейку?

Comment: Ну создайте копию списка без второй ячейки, наверное?

Comment: ну модуль рандом выбирает случайную ячейку из списка, мне нужно чтобы он не выбрал persons[1]

Answer (score 3):

У метода `choice` нет такого функционала, поэтому есть два варианта, написать свой обработчик:

```py
import random 
def random_choice(any_sequence, restricted_values):
    random_value = random.choice(any_sequence)
    while random_value not in restricted_values:
        random_value = random.choice(any_sequence)
    return random_value
```

Либо же передавать в `choice` склеенный список без нужного вам значения используя срезы:

```py
import random
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # 2 нужно  исключить
random.choice(some_list[1::] + some_list[2::])
```

P.S. либо создать копию списка без нужного значения, как предложил andreymal

Comment: а если надо исключить input() который выбрал пользователь со списка?

Comment: @SureDan а чем мое решение не подходит? Возьмите первый вариант и инпут пользователя передайте списком в функцию